# How to create a file in a subfolder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, directory, fopen

I'm trying to create a file using fopen in a subfolder in Matlab.

In my project directory I have a folder 'logs' so I tried this:

```
filename = 'log.txt';
date_format = 'mmm_dd_yyyy_HH:MM';
time_stamp = datestr(now, date_format);
file2 = fullfile('logs', strcat(time_stamp, filename));
fid = fopen(file2, 'w');
```

I get the error:

> The file name contains characters that are not contained in
>   the filesystem encoding. Certain operations may not work as expected.

I think it's a formatting issue but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Edit: In case it matters... Windows 7 and Matlab R2016a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the colon (:).

```
date_format = 'mmm_dd_yyyy_HH_MM';
```

In windows, filenames can't contain /:*"<> and ? marks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going nuts trying to figure out what was wrong with the folder... it was the timestamp...

Comment: Happens to me all the time.